# Why is the maximum variables count 4096 in PowerShell 5

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-core

Just for fun I ran that code:

```bsh
for ($i = 0; $i -le 9999; ++$i) { New-Variable $i $i -ErrorAction Stop }
```

*PowerShell 5.1* returned:

> `New-Variable : Cannot create variable 4073 because variable capacity 4096 is exceeded for this scope.`

But in *PowerShell 7.0.3* I changed `for` for creating **1 milliard** variables.
And I'm tired of waiting.. and canceled it when `pwsh` ate 7 Gb of my RAM...
`$i` was **18,401,068** at that moment!

It meant that *PS 7.0.3* has no limit for variables count or it is very high.

So why is there limit for **4096** variables count in *PS 5.1*?

Comment: Sure it's a bit arbitrary, but, I cannot imagine in a use case, where you'd ever even get close to this ceiling and if they did, it's time to refactor that code. That is the same question I've heard as to why ADDS allowed on 4B objects.

Comment: By setting the default variable $MaximumVariableCount you can increase this to 32768

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So why is there limit for 4096 variables count in PS 5.1?

Because someone, at some point, thought it was a good idea. That's it.

Maybe someone added it because variable operations in PowerShell are extremely expensive and not super memory efficient. Perhaps one of the developers ran a loop much like yours during testing and it ate up all the memory on his machine and it seemed like an easy stopgap. We may never know.

What we can tell from publicly available information is that the [limitation was removed long before](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2221) the GA release of PowerShell Core 6.0 - exactly because there was no good argument for keeping it.